# How to find out the validation accuracy of a model after the training process?

Tags: python, keras, conv-neural-network

I have trained a CNN model that recognises hand gestures. after the training part was I could not write down my val_acc value from console. Now I need to know the accuracy of my model?

Comment: Just load the data and call model.evaluate on it

Answer (score 1):

```
model.evaluate(Xtest, ytest)
```

This will give the value of loss, accuracy, f1_score etc..

Answer (score 1):

If you saved your model in a `hdf5` file (e.g. `mymodel.h5`) then you can evaluate it as follows:

```py
from keras.models import load_model

model = load_model('mymodel.h5')
metrics = model.evaluate(x_test, y_test)
```

Comment: what is x_test, y_test parameters?

Comment: They are the testing input and output sets (similar as x_train and y_train when training the network)

Comment: I am training on classification dataset where I have 10 classes. My testing and training dataset also have 10 classes. Then how do I put my parameters?

Comment: X are the inputs (images if you are classifying images) and y are the outputs (the classes)